# MyDefrag Script: Shutdown after Completion?

Tags: script, defragment, mydefrag

I'm looking for a script that shuts down my PC after it completed the procedure.

Preferably inside the standard scripts!

Comment: I can't comment on MyDefrag, but if you're scripting it already, you can follow it with a "shutdown /s" command which is available in XP onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

1. Open Settings.MyD
2. Change **WhenFinished(wait)** to
   **WhenFinished(shutdown)**